# How to create 3D shape button in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, 3d

I want to create 3D shape button i tried with shape but no luck. Below code i was used. I'm expecting result

[image: like this]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="line" >
<!-- Specify a gradient for the background -->
<gradient
    android:angle="45"
    android:centerColor="#00000000"
    android:centerX="0.75"
    android:endColor="#00000000"
    android:startColor="#55000066" />

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:topRightRadius="10dp" />

<stroke
    android:dashGap="0dp"
    android:dashWidth="10dp"
    android:width="50dp"
    android:color="#303030" />
```

I want to create like that button 
How to brought like that button in android. Please give you valuable ideas.

Comment: As far as I know, you're only going to create 2d stuff with xml shapes. You're probably better off trying it with an image or OpenGL

Comment: Do you want your buttons to look exactly the same as the buttons on your images?

Comment: Yes exactly, Do you have any idea about it?